# Projects from Eclipse Package Explorer

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I develop an Eclipse plugin project, I started a few days
ago and I have a question. My plugin works, my plugin
toolbar has a button, named Extract the project.
When I click on this button, the plugin writes the names of
the open projects from the Package Explorer.
How I can get the names of the projects from the package explorer?

I used ISelection, but unfortunately the ISelection object is empty. There are three open projects in package explorer.

Thanks for the answers!

Answer (score 0):

You do not need the selection.  You should start with the workspace root and start from there.

```
ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace().getRoot()
```

If you want to access the Java nature of a project use

```
JavaCore.create(iProject)
```

Comment: Actually JavaCore.create(IProject project) **DOES NOT CHECK** the existence or Java nature of this project (or so the documentation says). But the poster never explicitly mentionned opened _Java_ projects, just _opened projects_... From @iain's starting point with org.eclipse.core.resources.IResource.isAccessible(), you should be fine...

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the project and open the context menu. And go for the menu item "Restore from Local History...".

[image]